# What temperature should a crock pot slow cooker cook at?

Tags: temperature, slow-cooking, crockpot

I have a crock pot that will generate a low boil on the "Low" setting and dries out anything that is cooked for a long period. I'm wondering if the temperature regulator is too high, but I can't know that unless I know what the temperature is *supposed* to be.

Comment: Temperature of what? The liquid inside won't go past the boiling point. What really matters is the *power*, which determines how much water it's able to boil away in a given amount of time.

Comment: @Jefromi, good point! I suppose I could fill it with oil to take a temperature, but that doesn't seem productive. Do you have any alternate measuring techniques?

Comment: @Jefromi Should a slow cooker boil at all?  Would it negate the "slow" aspect if it did?

Comment: @event_jr Yes, slow cookers boil, just not too vigorously.

Answer (score 7):

I, like you, assumed that a slow cooker would have a temperature regulator. I took mine apart, in a bid to find the thermostat and adjust it -- and discovered that it does not have one.

Cheap slow cookers contain an heating element which delivers a constant low heat, and all you can do is choose between two or three levels of power. It does not stop supplying that heat when the contents reach a particular temperature. It just keeps pumping that heat into your food.

This means that -- as long as less heat is lost out of the cooker walls/lid than the element is putting in, the contents will keep getting hotter until they reach boiling point, whereupon  the energy will instead go into turning liquid into steam.

I don't know whether more expensive slow cookers have a proper thermostat. It would be good to know.

Comment: This is pretty much the answer. As far as I know, no slow cookers have "proper" thermostats; they don't need them. In this context, with respect to the OP's question, well, if it's boiling dry with a reasonable quantity of liquid and the lid on, it's too hot or the lid doesn't fit well enough. Perhaps you could edit your answer to include something along those lines; otherwise I might do it for you. (No reason to split the good stuff into two answers.)