# New crockpot cook times rule?

Tags: cooking-time, crockpot

Apparently many people really do not like the "newer" and "hotter" crock pots. With the temperature being hotter, many people are reporting their food being burnt.

Thing is because most of the recipes are for the old style crock pots.

Is there a good rule of thumb when it comes to cooking with the newer and hotter crock pots? I bought an oval 6.5 quart (6 l) crock pot but I'm half scared to use it because I don't want it to get burnt.

Comment: Please realize that your question makes sense only a very small area of the globe where "newer" and "hotter" crock pots are being sold. For everyone else having a chance of understanding your question, please include what temperature range you are talking about (in Fahrenheit is OK, if you can't manage to work in Celsius)

Comment: FWIW, see:  http://www.cookingforengineers.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=374

Comment: One tip that I have seen, and did myself (coincidently earlier this week) was fill my two crockpots (tiny one and big one) half full of water, set them on high, and saw that hey both brought the water to a slow simmer... this is what I would expect for a braising recipe, which is what crock pots are good at.

Comment: @belisarius It's not really about temperature; it's about power (and maybe how well the lid fits). If it's powerful enough, it'll boil off the water too fast and burn things. Though I live in the US, I don't happen to have a new overpowered crock pot either, but I still think the question's pretty understandable - it's really just asking "how do I figure out if my crock pot is overpowered, and if it is, what do I do about it?"

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/18867/1672 and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/30637/1672

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the newer crockpots have higher power (possibly to get food out of the 'danger-zone' of temperature faster).

However, slow cookers are designed to work with water inside the pot and as long as there is water in there, the temperature should not exceed the boiling point of water (~100C/212F).  So when you say that `people's foods are being burnt`, it suggests that the water is evaporating too fast.

I do have one of the new Crockpots and find the 'high' setting only good for getting the food and pot up to temperature (first 20 minutes) otherwise the slow cooker feels more like 'passive-aggressive cooker'.

Go ahead and give it a run.  But visit it a couple of times per hour and check on the water level.  As long as it's covering or almost covering the food, you're good.  You can adjust the starting water amount for next time (or add if things are dire).

If you have the digital one, it's nice to set the timer.  So when you forget to take the food off and drive to work (me, last week) you come home to a non-disaster.

Comment: I think the problem for me is that I want to be able to "leave" and go to work and make food, but apparently even on low it's burning peoples food. I guess maybe just adding more stock/liquid may help?>

Comment: @Mercfh yes, you should be able to leave and go to work.  However, I'd babysit it the first time.  That'll tell you how much stock/liquid you need as well as establish _some_ trust with the new appliance.  [Also:](http://magazine.foxnews.com/at-home/are-slow-cookers-safe#ixzz2Rt3rZHBf) 'Aileen Fanjul, a representative of the Crock-Pot® brand at Jarden Consumer Solutions, says the appliance doesn't need to be monitored at all times. "It is safe to leave your Crock-Pot® slow cooker on while you are out of the house," she states.'

Answer (score 2):

There's no right answer to this, every brand is different. Plus, you are assuming that you will have this problem when you don't know if the pot you bought is hotter than normal. In any case as long as you have enough liquid in it and use a low setting you shouldn't have to worry about anything burning.

My advice is to try a standard slow-cooker recipe and see how you do. If it cooks too fast then try bigger chunks.

Answer (score -2):

Not true. Try leaving pasta in for an extended period of time. It comes out practically nonexistent. So not all recipes can be left unattended.

Comment: Why are you cooking pasta in a slow cooker? Of course it would turn into mush.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.  The question is about a rule of thumb for converting recipes/cooking times from "old" to "new" style slow cookers, not whether pasta can be prepared in one of either style.