# Timing problem!

Tags: timing

I keep trying to use my slow cooker. I follow the recipes...put pulled pork in for the recommended 8 - 10 hours on slow....and then...it's still hard...I have ended up microwaving it...or leaving it for another 6 hours ON HIGH! This can't be right? This also happens when I slow cook a beef casserole - again  9 hours on slow - not melt in the mouth - more like chewy rubbery bits. Is my slow cooker broken? :(

Comment: Hello lisa and welcome! Please see this question, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18867/what-temperature-should-a-crock-pot-slow-cooker-cook-at as it should answer your question. Your slow cooker isn't broken, it is just the way they are.

Comment: in a nutshell: Not all slow cookers are created equal - and from what I read in various forums newer models *tend* to be somewhat on the hotter side. Perhaps your recipes are geared towards one of these?

Comment: I closed as a duplicate of a different question than the one suggested by Cindy, mostly because in a comment of it, there is a list of some of our questions on the timing of cooking meat low and slow. They should provide further information. (The one provided by Cindy is relevant too, of course)